# Print list of Dictionary<string, string> into file

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose that we declared the line below in our program :

```
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

so we want to print each member of this list into a file and in the separate page, but all in one document like `MyDoc.xps`. How can i do to achieve my end ?

**EDIT  :**  My difficulty is that how can i create new page in printing process?

Sorry if it duplicates with other questions, i can't get my answer in site threads. :|

Comment: Please read **EDIT** section.

Comment: Please explain _what you have tried_.

Comment: Are you doing this in Winforms or WPF? Is this specifically about .XPS documents?

Comment: Winforms. And note that i said that `like MyDoc.xps`

Comment: @codesparkle : I talk about how to create new page in printing process and *.XPS is not the format that i want to create! It is general question!!!!!!!

Comment: well, if ShadowWizard's answer doesn't help you, why don't you follow Oded's advice and actually post the code you've written up 'til now (= "*what you have tried*")?

Comment: I dont know why vote me down :-/

Comment: You got downvoted (not by me by the way) because you didn't explain your problem clearly and didn't say what you tried so far.

Comment: Okay! I accepted these downvotes because of your reason :) sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that works is the following:

1. Make the list global class member
2. Use the `PrintDocument` class under `System.Drawing.Printing` and use its `PrintPage` event to set the pages one by one.

Sample code:

```
private List<Dictionary<string, string>> myList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
private int pageIndex = 0;
private void PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
    document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(document_PrintPage);
    document.Print();
}

void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (pageIndex >= myList.Count)
    {
        e.HasMorePages = false;
        return;
    }

    Dictionary<string, string> curData = myList[pageIndex];
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines.Add("Items count: " + curData.Count);
    curData.Keys.ToList().ForEach(key =>
    {
        lines.Add(string.Format("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, curData[key]));
    });
    e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Join("\n", lines), this.Font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, 0, 0);
    pageIndex++;
    e.HasMorePages = pageIndex < myList.Count;
}
```

On every page printed, the `document_PrintPage` method will be called. As long as you won't set `e.HasMorePages` to false, it will keep printing new pages.

**Edit**: to force creating `.xps` file just add those two lines when creating the print document:

```
document.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
document.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "myfile.xps";
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) It is my question's answer :)

Comment: Cheers @Hossein it's based on old code I got and recalled when seeing your question.